# ngx-perfect-scrollbar show hide footer

Tags: angular, scroll, footer

I am trying to make the footer slide in/out depending on the scrolling.
So far the only thing I got to work is to show the footer with **psYReachEnd**, but how do I "tell" the footer to slide back out when I scrolled for ex 100px up ?

```
public onReachEnd(): void {
this.zone.run(() => {
  this.status = true;
});
console.log('show footer');}




<perfect-scrollbar (psYReachEnd)="onReachEnd()"><div>content</div><div id="footer" class="container-fluid" [ngClass]="status ? 'show' : 'hide'">footer content</div></perfect-scrollbar>
```

Comment: You can use `psScrollUp` event and check manually the position and hide the footer

Comment: could you please elaborate?...I am an angular total newbie

Comment: `(psScrollUp)="onScrollUp($event)"` and create a method `onScrollUp(event)` and check event properties you will find scroll position there

Comment: You can check the current scroll position by `event.target.scrollTop` and find the maximum scroll height by `event.target.scrollHeight` and write your logic easily

Comment: still can't figure this out

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.If anyone else is interested here is the working solution ( for me )

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

status = false;

@HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
onScrollY(event) {
if (event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop >= event.target.scrollHeight) {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.status = true;
  });
} else {
  this.zone.run(() => {
   this.status = false;
 });
}
}




<perfect-scrollbar (psScrollY)="onScrollY($event)">
   <div [ngClass]="status ? 'show' : 'hide'">content</div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

ps: if there is another more Angular solution please post